# Observable Shorthand

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm wondering if there is a better way (read: shorter) to write the following function in Typescript/Angular2. I find myself in a situation a lot of times where I'm caching observable server data and returning the cached value if it exists. My way (below) seems to be a bit overkill.

```html
getUser(){
    return Observable.create(s => {
      if(!this.user)
        this.connection.identity((err, res) => {
          this.user = res;
          s.next(res);
          s.complete();
        })
      else{
        s.next(this.user);
        s.complete();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your implementation be a little bit longer? You don't appear to handle the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little shorter and it handles errors:

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
import "rxjs/add/observable/bindNodeCallback";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
...
getUser() {
  return this.user ?
    Observable.of(this.user) :
    Observable.bindNodeCallback(
      this.connection.identity.bind(this.connection),
      res => this.user = res
    )();
}
```

Comment: It worked once I imported my Observable as import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx instead of as import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'

Comment: You can use the minimal `Observable` import if you also import the creators you wish to use. I've updated the answer with the required imports.